# How do I downgrade Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying downgrade my latest installed Xcode 3.2.5 to older versions(3.1.x etc). Otherwise i'm unable to use iPad 3.2 simulator, iPhone 4.0 simulator and all in Xcode, eventhough i changed the deployment target to 3.2, 4.0 etc., which causes some issues to test really on these simulators. I also really want to know how do i uninstall existing latest Xcode and install some older Xcode versions which supported by Mac.
I searched google, didn't find suitable answer for downgrading Xcode versions. Could someone please guide me how do i do that?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should have less of a focus on testing on specific versions of the *Simulator*, and more of a focus on testing on *devices*. Since all iPads can upgrade to 4.2 free of charge, I personally don't see the purpose of testing on anything less, but maybe you have specific circumstances that have all your users on 3.2 or something.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to install different versions side-by-side by installing it in a different directly. I use /Developer-v.x for older or beta versions. If you really want to get rid of your old one, you'll have to delete the /Developer directory and re-install your target version in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions in /Developer/About XCode and iOS SDK.pdf, in the section titled "Uninstalling Xcode Developer Tools".   Then install the XCode version you want.  For more gory details of XCode installation, see the [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/XcodeCoexistence/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Details/Details.html).